# Jquery UI autocomplete error help (collectionResults is not defined)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jquery ui autocomplete, and everything is working fine except when I try and select a value from the drop down. Every time I click a value in the dropdown, I get the following error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: collectionResults is not defined

from:
jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js:19

these are my referenced libraries:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.position.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
```

I cannot find anything on the interwebz about this collectionResults error :( please help!

as requested, here is the code I have:

```
$("#searchTerms").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: appSettings["SearchApiUrl"] + "/?searchTerm=" + term,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 3,
        });
```

thanks

Comment: Please show the code you're working with (in addition to the `script` tags above)

Comment: Do you have any variables called `collectionResults`? I don't think jQueryUI uses a variable by that name

Comment: I dont, it says the error is coming from the minified autocomplete library

Comment: You probably already figured this out, but ... add jQuery library **before** calling the jquery-ui/autocomplete